# how can prevent Unnecessary re-rendering childs component on changing a state in parent component despite using memo and useCallback in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have dashboard application that has a sidebar and a content body that routes placed there , I define a state in my app.js for open and close sidebar on clicking a button , but when i open and close my sidebar and the state changed , my components that routes all urls in my content body call API again; Despite I use React.memo in my childs component and I use useCallback for my open and close sidebar function however it call again APIs everytime after open and close the sidebar , please tell me where is my problem .
some part of my codes is in below :
App.js ===>

```js
function App(props){
.
.
.
const [open , setOpen] = useState(true);
. 
.
.
const openSideBar = useCallback(() => {
    setOpen(!open);
  } , [open]);

.
.
.
return (
    <div className={clsx("drt_pos_relative" ,  
                        direction === 'rtl' ? "drt_App" : "drt_ltr_App" , 
                        !open ? "drt_close" : "drt_open")}> 
      <AuthProvider>
        
          <BrowserRouter>
              <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <I18nProvider locale={lang}>
                  <Router>
                    <CustomProvider value={lang}>
                        <AuthConsumer>
                            {
                              ({getUser}) => {
                                if(!flag){
                                    getUser().then(result => {
                                      if(result !== undefined && result !== null){
                                          setUser(result);
                                          setFlag(true);
                                      }
                                      
                                  });
                                  }
                                   
                                  return (
                                    <Fragment>
                                        {/* header */}
                                        <Header 
                                          open={open} 
                                          changeCulture={handleChangeLang}
                                          culture={lang}
                                          user={user !== undefined && user !== null ? user : {}}/>
                                        {/* sidebar */}
                                        {window.innerWidth < 768 ? <SideBar 
                                            locale={lang}
                                            open={!open}
                                            handleOpen={openSideBar}
                                            user={user}
                                            links={links}
                                            loading={loading} /> :
                                          <SideBar 
                                            locale={location.split('/')[1]}
                                            open={open}
                                            handleOpen={openSideBar} 
                                            user={user}
                                            links={links}
                                            loading={loading}/>}  
                                        {/* content */}
                                        <div className={clsx("drt_ContentBody" , open ? "drt_ActiveSideBar" : '' )}>
                                          <div className="drt_Content">
                                            {/* Breadcrumbs */}
                                            <div className="drt_breadCrumb">
                                              <Grid container>
                                                <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={8} style={{ padding: '10px 0'}}>
                                                  <Route>{({ location }) => handleBreadcrumb(location)}</Route>
                                                </Grid>
                                              </Grid>
                                            </div>
                                            <Routes 
                                              locale={location.split('/')[1]} 
                                              user={user}
                                              handleLocation={handleCurrentLocation} />
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        {/* footer */}
                                        <Footer open={open} />
                                    </Fragment>
                                  );
                              }
                            }
                        </AuthConsumer>
                        
                    </CustomProvider>
                  </Router>
                </I18nProvider>
              </ThemeProvider>
          </BrowserRouter>
      </AuthProvider>
    </div>
  );

}
```

sidebar.js ===>

```js
function SideBar(props){
.
.
.
return  (
        <div 
            className={
                clsx("drt_SideBar",  props.open ? "drt_Open" : '')}>
            {/* sidebar button */} // ======> here is button of close and open sidebar
            <a className={clsx("drt_OpenBtn", !props.open ? "drt_IsClose" : '')} 
                            onClick={props.handleOpen}>
                <i className="fal fa-chevron-double-right" />
            </a>
            {/* logo */}
            <a href="#" className="drt_Logo">
                <img 
                    src={props.open ? logoImg : logoMiniImg} 
                    className={clsx(!props.open ? "drt_MiniLogo" : '' )} />
            </a>

            {
                !props.loading && props.links !== undefined && props.links.length > 0 ? 
                    (<List
                        component="ul"
                        className="drt_Menu"
                        >
        
                        {
                            props.links.map(function(link , index){
                                if(link.Childs && link.Childs.length === 0){
                                    return (
                                        <ListItem 
                                            key={index}
                                            selected={_location.pathname === link.Url ? true : false}
                                            classes={{root : props.open ? "drt_LinkItem" : "drt_SelectedLinkOnCloseSidebar", 
                                                        selected : props.open ? "drt_SelectedLink" : 'drt_SelectedLinkOnCSB'}} >
                                            <ListItemIcon classes={{root : props.open ? "drt_ItemIcon" : "drt_itemIconOnClose"}}>
                                                <i className={link.Icon} />
                                            </ListItemIcon>
                                            {props.open ? <ListItemText primary={link.Name} /> : '' }
                                            
                                            {link.Url && link.Url.trim() !== '' ? <Link to={link.Url} /> : ''}
                                        </ListItem>
                                    );
                                }
                                else{
                                    return (
                                        <Fragment key={index}>
                                            <ListItem 
                                                selected={isSelected(link.Id) ? true : false}
                                                onClick={e => handleClick(link.Id , e)}
                                                classes={{
                                                    root : props.open ? "drt_LinkItemCollaps" : "drt_SelectedLinkOnCloseSidebar" , 
                                                    selected :props.open ? "drt_LinkItemColSelected" : "drt_LinkItemColSelectedOnClose" }}
                                                >
                                                    
                                                    
                                                {handleOpen(link.Id) ? <span className="drt_CollapseParent" /> : ''}
                                                <ListItemIcon classes={{root : props.open ? "drt_ItemIcon" : "drt_itemIconOnClose"}}>
                                                    <i className={link.Icon} />
                                                </ListItemIcon>
                                                {props.open ? <ListItemText primary={link.Name} /> : ''}
                                                {props.open ? (handleOpen(link.Id) ? <ExpandLess className="drt_ExpandIcon" /> : <ExpandMore className="drt_ExpandIcon" />) : null }
                                                {!props.open ? <div className="drt_HoverOnClose">
                                                    <ListItem 
                                                    selected={handleOpen(link.Id) ? true : false}
                                                    onClick={e => handleClick(link.Id , e)}
                                                    classes={{
                                                        root : "drt_LinkItemCollapsOnCloseSidebar" , 
                                                        selected : "drt_LinkItemColSelectedOnClose" }}
                                                    >
                                                        {handleOpen(link.Id) ? <span className="drt_CollapseParent" /> : ''}
                                                        <ListItemText primary={link.Name} className="drt_ListItemText"/>
                                                    </ListItem>
                                                        {link.Childs.map(function(item , index){
                                                            return (
                                                                <List component="li" disablePadding key={index}>
                                                                    <ListItem classes={{
                                                                                root : "drt_LinkItemOnCloseSidebar" , 
                                                                                selected : "drt_SelectedLinkOnCSB" }} 
                                                                        selected={_location.pathname === item.Url ? true : false}>
                                                                        <ListItemIcon classes={{root : "drt_ItemIconChild" }}>
                                                                            <i className={item.Icon} />
                                                                        </ListItemIcon>
                                                                        <ListItemText primary={item.Name} />
                                                                        {item.Url && item.Url.trim() !== '' ? <Link to={item.Url} /> : ''}
                                                                        
                                                                    </ListItem>
                                                                </List>
                                                            );
                                                        })}
                                                </div> : ''}
                                            </ListItem>
                                            {props.open ? <Collapse in={handleOpen(link.Id)} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit component="ul"
                                                classes={{
                                                    container: "drt_Collapse" ,
                                                     entered: "drt_EnteredCollapse"}}>
                                                {link.Childs.map(function(item , index){
                                                    return (
                                                        <List component="li" disablePadding key={index}>
                                                            <ListItem classes={{
                                                                        root : props.open ? "drt_LinkItem" : "drt_SelectedLinkOnCloseSidebar" , 
                                                                        selected : "drt_SelectedLink" }} 
                                                                selected={_location.pathname === item.Url ? true : false}>
                                                                <ListItemIcon classes={{root : props.open ? "drt_ItemIconChild" : "drt_itemIconOnCloseChild"}}>
                                                                    <i className={item.Icon} />
                                                                </ListItemIcon>
                                                                {props.open ? <ListItemText primary={item.Name} /> : ''}
                                                                {item.Url && item.Url.trim() !== '' ? <Link to={item.Url} /> : ''}
                                                                
                                                            </ListItem>
                                                        </List>
                                                    );
                                                })}
                                            </Collapse> : null}
                                            
                                        </Fragment>
                                        
                                    );
                                }
                            })
                        }
        
                    </List>) : 
                    (<div className="drt_loading"> 
                        <CircularProgress />
                    </div>)
            }
        
            
        
        </div> 
    );


}

export default React.memo(SideBar);
```

Comment: useCallback creates a new function on every open change so it’s efficiently useless. State setter shouldn’t access the state directly, this is what setter function is for. Should be `const openSideBar = useCallback(() => setOpen(open => !open), [])`. I’m unable to embrace the whole case because it’s verbose but if this solves the issue, that’s the answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer , you mean that I delete the open state in bracket of useCallback? first I did not write open in [] of useCallback and my sidebar only close and then not work in opening and closing

Comment: It should be exactly what I wrote. Empty bracket. And `open => !open` setter function. Both of them.

Comment: i tried it now but still APIs call after open and close sidebar

Comment: Then the problem is specific to your components or router configuration and not useCallback. As for useCallback, that's what was wrong with it. If components call APIs on every re-render and not just mount, this may be need to be changed.